# Shopping Cart Price Rule for items from two categories

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart-price-rules, price-rules

I was recently requested to create a Price rule which applies a discount of 15% to shopping cart containing items from two different categories. I've configured the Conditions as below:

[image: Conditions]

However I'm not able to work out the Actions rules, adding 2 categories (128, 129) in wouldn't help.

I'm using Magento ver. 1.9.2.2.

Any thoughts?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can try changing **ALL** to **ANY** on the top.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! The rule is intended to use for any purchase of 1 item from category 129 and more than 1 item from category 128, would ANY work though?

Comment: Then you should stick with **ALL**

Comment: BTW, cart price rule will only occur on checkout page. Does the rule apply on checkout page?

Comment: I have yet to put anything in Actions, the promo code wouldn't work on checkout stating there is an error.